# Java accessibility: Report task complete to blind user

Tags: java, swing, accessibility

I'm using the Java Accessibility Bridge to connect the JAWS screen reader to my Swing application.  I would like to alert the user when a search operation has completed.  What is the best way to do this?

I have tried jumping the focus to a TextBox, but this didn't result in an audio alert.  Triggering a MessageBox is not acceptable.  I don't have a progress bar (just a custom animated spinner)

Many thanks!

Comment: ..[`Toolkit.beep()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#beep--)?

Comment: Nice idea @AndrewThompson, but that may drive the other users nuts.  Any way I can do this only when operating under a screen-reader?

Comment: I don't know.  Can the Swing GUI ***tell*** when it is running under a screen reader?  The alternative is to place an accessible control on the UI to allow the user to decide.